# Can I install Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 after installing ASP.NET 5 RC1?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have installed ASP.NET 5 RC1 on VS 2015 RTM, and then found that VS 2015 Update 1 is released containing ASP.NET 5 Beta 8. Will I need to re-intsall ASP.NET 5 RC1 after installing VS update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go ahead to install Update 1 and it should work.

Note that Update 1 even updates ASP.NET 5 to RC1 Update 1.